# Limit cat using cut to values 1 or over I do n

Tags: linux, apache, command-line-arguments

In an attempt to debug Apache on a very busy server, we have used strace to log all our processes.   Now, I have 1000s of individual straces in a folder and I need to find the ones that have a value of 1.0+ or greater.  This is the command we used to generate the straces

```
 mkdir /strace; ps auxw | grep httpd | awk '{print"-p " $2}' | xargs strace -o /strace/strace.log -ff -s4096 -r
```

This has generated files with the name strace.log.29382  (Where 29382 is the PID of the process).

Now, if I run this command:

```
for i in `ls /strace/*`; do echo $i; cat $i | cut -c6-12 | sort -rn | head -c 8; done
```

it will output the filename and top runtime value.  i.e.

```
/strace/strace.log.19125
0.13908
/strace/strace.log.19126
0.07093
/strace/strace.log.19127
0.09312
```

What I am looking for is only to output those with a value of 1.0 or greater.

Sample data:  https://pastebin.com/Se89Jt1i

This data does not contain any thing 1.0+   But its the first set of #s trying to filter against only.

What I do not want to have show up

```
      0.169598 close(85)                 = 0
```

What I do want to find

```
     1.202650 accept4(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(4557), sin_addr=inet_addr("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")}, [16], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 85
```

My cat sorts the values so the highest value in the file is always first.

Comment: You are already using `awk`, and IIRC `awk` can do floating point. Personally, I'd code up the entire for-echo-cat-cut-sort-head thing in Python.

Comment: An alternative is to cook up some regex and use `grep`, but personally I'd not go there.

Comment: (Opps, got my substr args confused. Revised:) `for $(ls ..)` is considered bad form, but assuming there are no spaces or other non-alpha-numeric chars in your filenames, it seems like you're very close. something like `for i in $(ls /strace/*) ; do awk '{val=substr($0,6,6);print val "\t" $0}' $i | sort -rn | awk -fName="$i" 'NR==1{print fName"\t" $0}';done` . Good luck.

Comment: There is a  space buffer before the number, which is why I am using cut 6-12 to get just the number.  Your example returns.

    awk: fatal: can't open source file `Name=/strace/strace.log.21849' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: can't open source file `Name=/strace/strace.log.21850' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: can't open source file `Name=/strace/strace.log.21851' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: I don't have an easy way to test your question. Please edit your Q to include a small sample of the data in your file. Going out for a while. Will check back when I can Good luck.

Comment: c'mon, "small sample of data" doesn't require pastebin. Qs on S.O. should be self contained and not required going to external sites. A line of data that should pass your test and one that doesn't pass the test should be enough. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the pastebin.  I could not get the white space padding to show up.  I will post a single line of each above.

Comment: `for i in $(ls /strace/*) ; do awk '{val=substr($0,6,6);print val "\t" $0}' $i | sort -rn | awk -vfName="$i" 'NR==1{print fName"\t" $0}';done` oops, dropped `-v` while editing that bit of code. Adjust the `6,6` to print the section of the line that you want to sort by. And sorry, but I won't be online tomorrow. Hopefully you can see what is going on now with `-vfName=...`. I would recommend getting the inside of the `for` loop to work with one file, then "turn on" the for loop surrounding.

Comment: To test the `awk ... "$i" ...|sort ..| awk ...` and fix any remaing problems, try to understand what the code is doing, so just run the first part (`awk .. "$i"`) and understand that output, then add the `|sort` and then add the final `awk`. Sorry, but will be offline for 24-36 hrs. If you reallly need resolution, write a new Q, as older Qs have very few new readers. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As I am more used to use perl, a solution with perl which should be possible to translate with awk.

One-liner

```
perl -ane 'BEGIN{@ARGV=</strace/*>}$max=$F[0]if$F[0]>$max;if(eof){push@A,$ARGV if$max>1;$max=0};END{print"$_\n"for@A}'
```

No need to sort files to get the maximum value just storing it in a variable. The part which can be interresting to modify to get information:

```
push@A,$ARGV
```

can be changed to

```
push@A,"$ARGV:$max"
```

to get the value.

How it works :

- -a flag: from perl -h : `autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into @F)` by default delimited by one ore more spaces.
- `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` blocks are executed at the beginning and the end, the part which is not in thoose blocks is executed for each line as with awk.
- `</strace/*>` is a glob matching which gives a list of files
- `@ARGV` is a special array which contains command line argument (here list of files to process)
- `eof` is a function which returns true when current line is the last of current file
- `$ARGV` is current file name
- `push` to append elements to an array

The script version with warnings which are useful to fix bugs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub BEGIN {
    use File::Glob ();
    @ARGV = glob('/strace/*');
}

my (@A,@F);
my $max = 0;

while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    @F = split(' ', $_, 0);
    $max = $F[0] if $F[0] > $max;
    if (eof) {
        push @A, "${ARGV}:$max" if $max > 1;
        $max = 0;
    }
}

print "$_\n" foreach (@A);
```